# tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1") added while creating table in hive is making some issue in Imapla

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I have created a table in **Hive**, and need to load the data using **CSV** file. So while creating table i mention the table property "**tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")**".

[image]

And I have loaded data into my table. This is my input file content

[image]

After loading data i am able to see the output in **Hive console**. Where as when i am fetching data from the same table in Impala, it is giving some problem and **not skipping the header** as i mentioned at the time of creation of table.

The impala result is like below.
[image]

Now my question is 
`Why Impala is not able to take the table properties and skipping the header.?`
Please give me some information about it.

Comment: It is a known issue. There is a ticket ([IMPALA-1740](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1740)) in Impala Jira related to it.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove headers. Probably, it is the easiest workaround for the issue.